# Adding artifacts at one level up in root folder

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an artifact called onnxruntime.dll which are downloaded from pipeline and its folder structure is like this MyProject_x64_windows/bin/Nodes/onnxruntime.dll . I would like this artifact to be downloaded at one level up i.e. MyProject_x64_windows/bin/onnxruntime.dll

I am not sure how it is getting downloaded at that level and how can I fix this. I cant copy the complete YAML but am providing the one which I think is required:

```
  variables:
  IppRoot:        $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages/IPP  
  ONNXXRoot:       $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/packages/ONNXRuntime
  
  - stage: MyProject

    jobs:
      
      - job: MyProject_Build
        strategy:
          matrix:
            win:
              imageName:            'windows-2019'
              OrzRootSuffix:        'x64-windows-staticlib'
              osSuffix:             'windows'
              LibFT4222Suffix:      'windows'
              matlabVersion:        '9.6.0-2'
              extraCmakeOptions:    '-D MyProject_ONNX_SUPPORT=On
                                    -D ONNX_RUNTIME_ROOT:PATH=$(ONNXRoot)'
         pool:
          vmImage: $(imageName)

        steps:
        - checkout: self
          lfs: true
        
        - task: UniversalPackages@0
          displayName: 'Download pre-build ONXX Runtime headers and libraries'
          inputs:
            command:            'download'
            vstsFeed:           'MyProjectPackages'
            vstsFeedPackage:    'microsoft.ml.onxxruntime'
            vstsPackageVersion: '*' # use the latest
            downloadDirectory:  '$(ONNXRoot)'

 
        - download: SCMockPipeline
          displayName: Download SCMock
          artifact: scmock
          condition: eq(variables['Agent.OS'], 'Windows_NT')

        - script: python -m pip install jinja2
          displayName: Install python jinja2 template engine

        - task: CMake@1
          displayName: CMake configure
          inputs:
            workingDirectory: '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
            cmakeArgs: '-G Ninja
                        $(extraCmakeOptions)                        
                        -DLibFT4222_ROOT=$(LibFT4222Root)
                        -DIPP_ROOT=$(IppRoot)
                        -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
                        -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
                        $(Build.SourcesDirectory)'

        - task: CMake@1
          displayName: CMake build
          inputs:
            workingDirectory:   '$(Build.BinariesDirectory)'
            cmakeArgs:          '--build . --target install'

        - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          displayName: 'Publish MyProject'
          inputs:
            targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)
            artifactName: 'MyProject_x64-$(osSuffix)'    
            
        - task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          displayName: Download MyProject artifact
          inputs:
            artifact: 'MyProject_x64-$(osSuffix)'
            path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyProject_x64-$(osSuffix)'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to set the destination directory in the `DownloadPipelineArtifact` task to download the artifact to the `bin` folder.

```
- task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
          displayName: 'Publish MyProject'
          inputs:
            targetPath: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/bin/Nodes/onnxruntime.dll
            artifactName: 'MyProject_x64-$(osSuffix)'

- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
          displayName: Download MyProject artifact
          inputs:
            artifact: 'MyProject_x64-$(osSuffix)'
            path: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/MyProject_x64-$(osSuffix)/bin'
```